# Can the reverseProxyEndpointPort on local dev cluster run?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am attempting to enable the reverse proxy functionality of service fabric on a local 5 node dev cluster.  This functionality seems to work fine on a deployed cluster, but not on the dev cluster?

Both the deployed and the local dev cluster are on 5.4.145.9494.
The local dev is on vs 2015, service fabric sdk 2.4.145.9494

I have referenced [How to configure and enable Azure Service Fabric Reverse Proxy for an existing on-premises cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881031/how-to-configure-and-enable-azure-service-fabric-reverse-proxy-for-an-existing-o/39020576)
but the clustermanifesttemplate, specifically w7 in my case, doesn't seem to reference these values.  Only the "older" ApplicationGateway/Http.

If I enable

```
<Section Name="ApplicationGateway/Http">
    <Parameter Name="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
</Section>
```

and then deploy an application, after a few minutes my (local)cluster crashes.

Current node type example for reference:

```
<NodeType Name="NodeType0">
    <Endpoints>
        <ClientConnectionEndpoint Port="19000" />
        <LeaseDriverEndpoint Port="19001" />
        <ClusterConnectionEndpoint Port="19002" />
        <HttpGatewayEndpoint Port="19080" Protocol="http" />
        <ServiceConnectionEndpoint Port="19006" />
        <HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint Port="19081" Protocol="http" />
        <ApplicationEndpoints StartPort="30001" EndPort="31000" />
    </Endpoints>
</NodeType>
```

Additional information:
Windows event viewer is showing

```
HostedService: _Node_0 on node id bf865279ba277deb864a976fbf4c200e terminated unexpectedly with code 3221225781 and process name FabricApplicationGateway.exe
```

port usage:

```
netstat -anob | find "19081"
<no return>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your other node types. On a local cluster, each endpoint needs a unique port on each node type because it's all running on one machine. I'm guessing something else is already using port 19081 on another node type.