# Service Fabric Reverse Proxy not working

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I have reverse proxy properly configured on both local and deployed cluster but Iam unable to access my owin based webAPI on reverse proxy port here is the response I get on this port
[image]

I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881031/how-to-configure-and-enable-azure-service-fabric-reverse-proxy-for-an-existing-o) and am sure that its configured properly. The question is do I need to change some thing in my project or code to make it work.
Here is my service manifest for the webAPI :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceManifest Name="BimWebApiPkg"
                 Version="1.0.9"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType. 
         This name must match the string used in RegisterServiceType call in Program.cs. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="BimWebApiType" />
  </ServiceTypes>

  <!-- Code package is your service executable. -->
  <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.9">
    <EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>BimWebApi.exe</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
      </ExeHost>
    </EntryPoint>
  </CodePackage>

  <!-- Config package is the contents of the Config directoy under PackageRoot that contains an 
       independently-updateable and versioned set of custom configuration settings for your service. -->
  <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.9" />

  <Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
           listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
           replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->

      <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="80" />

    </Endpoints>
  </Resources>
</ServiceManifest>
```

I also tried without specifying any port but that too didn't work.

Comment: See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#uri-format-for-addressing-services-by-using-the-reverse-proxy

Comment: Specifically `ServiceInstanceName: This is the fully-qualified name of the deployed service instance that you are trying to reach without the "fabric:/" scheme. For example, to reach the fabric:/myapp/myservice/ service, you would use myapp/myservice.`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the url is incorrect. It's missing the part where you should have app name and service name specified. Try this -

http://localhost:19081/YOUR_APP_NAME/BimWebApi/api/TestAPI/GetString/

Comment: Yeah I also figured out the same thing, is there a way to get rid of YOUR_APP_NAME/BimWebApi from the url ?

Comment: @Kayani No if you want to use Reverse Proxy. It requires app and service name to resolve the node where to send the request at. On the other hand, you could try SF DNS Service. Check out [DNS Service in Azure Service Fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice).